# how to compare value returned by database query with a value in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

i want to check whether an email is present in my database or not and then execute furthur statements based on the value returned.....my code is as follows.....

```
private void deleterecordbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (deleterecordtextBox.Text != "")
            {
                MyOleDbConnection.Open();
                string vsql = string.Format("delete from login where Email='{0}'", deleterecordtextBox.Text);
                OleDbCommand vcom = new OleDbCommand(vsql, MyOleDbConnection.vcon);
                vcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Record deleted successfully!!");
                MyOleDbConnection.Close();
                deleterecordtextBox.Clear();
                this.Close();
                this.ReferToLogindb.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No record selected");
            }
        }
```

Comment: What have you tried? How does your code not work at the moment? Think about this logically...how do you verify if something is in the database? You perform a `SELECT` statement...no?....

Comment: soooo... what exactly is the problem?  please clarify...

Comment: What's problem you got with your code?

Answer (score 0):

run a query on the database that counts the number of rows that contain the email address and do a conditional statement on the result to check if its 1 or greater and if so do your other code

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to know if a record has been deleted AFTER your query execute, then get the return value from ExecuteNonQuery. It returns the number of rows affected by your command.

If there is no record that matches your query the return value will be zero
[See MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx)

```
int recordsDeleted = vcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
if(recordsDeleted != 0)
   .....
else
   ....
```

By the way, your code has a potential problem called Sql Injection and you could have problems with connection not closed correctly. I suggest to change to:

```
using(OleDbConnection oleConn = GetConnection())
{
    oleConn.Open();
    string vsql = "delete from login where Email=@mail";
    OleDbCommand vcom = new OleDbCommand(vsql, oleConn);
    vcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mail", deleterecordtextBox.Text);
    int recordsDeleted = vcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if(recordsDeleted != 0)
        MessageBox.Show("Record deleted successfully!!");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Record not found!");
 }
 deleterecordtextBox.Clear();
 ......
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to retrieve a particular field of a record and display it on a form inside a textbox.....

Comment: That's another question. You need a SqlCommand, a SqlDataReader and a loop on every record. There are numerous samples on MSDN. Search for SqlDataReader. Like this one directly on the page of SqlDataReader http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Except all other recommendations speciffied,
change:

```
if (deleterecordtextBox.Text != "")
```

to:

```
if (deleterecordtextBox.Text !=string.Empty)
```